# VS Code syntax highlighting for angular template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

How does syntax highlighting for angular template in VScode as in WebStorm IDE or Visual Studio (may be some extension or settings):

when we use component variables, it has another color.

and also it would be nice to see another color for angular directives, that will differ them from simple html attributes.

[example how that looks by default in web storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7aC.png)

or for example, something like that  VScode extension for [Aurelia javascript framework](https://aurelia.io/blog/2016/10/11/introducing-the-aurelia-vs-code-plugin/)

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a vscode extension that will specifically highlight angular components in html files?

Comment: Yes, I ask about this and also may be we can use some VS Code settings for customisation syntax highlight.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [angular2-inline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline) extension.

Comment: unfortunately, this extension works only for templates that placed in typescript files, but I want the similar feature for html files.

Comment: I use this VSC extension: [vscode-angular-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ghaschel.vscode-angular-html)

Comment: @j3ff You should post this as an answer, honestly. I could not find the extension beforehand for some reason. Your comment made my life so much easier!

Comment: @InDieTasten it was one of the answers, but idk why, the moderators deleted it